# Direct sum, product, sum and intersection of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Is is true that in general the direct sum of an ideal of a ring with itself is equal to the square of that ideal (i.e. the product with itself). More generally, is $I \oplus J = IJ$ for I,J ideals?

Moreover, what can be said in general about the relation of the direct sum, the sum of ideals and their intersection?

In the particular case of $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and the ideal $I = (2,1+\sqrt{-5})$, I know that $I^2 = (2)$, but I think one can also show that $I^2 = R^2$ as $R$-modules. Is this true?

Comment: No, $IJ\subseteq I\cap J$, but $I\oplus J$ is not in general.

Comment: No, you can see from the trivial example of $I = J = R$ that $I \oplus J$ and $IJ$ are not usually isomorphic. The natural map $I \otimes_R J \to IJ$ is not an isomorphism in general, either, but it is for invertible modules. In your example, you're considering a nonzero fractional ideal of a Dedekind domain, which one can show is always invertible. Since $I^{\otimes 2} = (2)$, you instead have $I^{\otimes 2} \cong R$.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn I don't see why you mention the tensor product here.

Comment: @baltazar In [your comment below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4047295/direct-sum-product-sum-and-intersection-of-ideals?noredirect=1#comment8359207_4047332) you wrote the tensor product. But I guess that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason for the equality $I+J=IJ.$ If you want a specific example, consider $I=J=(2)\subset \mathbb Z.$ Then $I+J=(2)$ whereas $IJ=(4).$ In general we have the relationship $IJ\subset I\cap J\subset I+J.$ The containment $IJ\subset I\cap J$ is actually an equality if $I$ and $J$ are **comaximal**, that is, if $I+J=R$ is the unit ideal (as long as $R$ is commutative).

In your particular example it is true that $I^2=(2).$ However, $1\in R,$ so $1=1^2\in R^2.$ Thus $R^2=R$ as ideals.

This is all contained in chapter 7 of Dummit and Foote's book.

Comment: Is $I \otimes I = I + I$ in general? Regarding the second part of the question, sorry, I meant to ask about $I^2 \cong R^2$ as $R$-modules, not as ideals. My mistake. I edited the question.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $I\otimes I.$ If you mean the product of ideals then no, as I said in my answer we have strict containment $I^2\subset I+I=I$ in general. Since $R$-submodules of $R$ are exactly the ideals, the statement still holds true.

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be $I \oplus I$.

Comment: Is that a direct sum as $R$-modules or the internal sum as ideals in $R$? If the former then no, there is no isomorphism in general. If the latter then yes, vacuously.